# filter choices for many to many field in form django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want "picking_person" to be selectable only from "members" of a Group. I ill trying some **init** and filters, but i cannot find solution. Profile model does not connected with Group model. Group model have two attributes which are connected to Profile:

```
class Group(models.Model):
 members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Profile, blank=True, default=Profile, related_name="members"
    )
 picking_person = models.ManyToManyField(
        Profile, blank=True, default=Profile, related_name="picking_person"
    )
```

forms.py:

```
class ChoosePersonPickingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['picking_person']
```

views.py:

```
def choose_person_to_pick_players(request, pk):
    group = Group.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ChoosePersonPickingForm(instance=group)
    group_members = group.members.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ChoosePersonPickingForm(request.POST, instance=group)
        form.save()
        return redirect('group', group.id)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "choose-picking-person.html", context)
```

Can you help me to find solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an aside - are you sure you want Picking Person to be ManyToMany, is there more than one in a group?

Anyhow - as the list of pickable persons may be different for each form, you want to use the init function in your form to generate the options as it is called when the form instantiates.  You can use the instance you are already passing in to help with the queryset. Obviously this will only work for an existing group.

```
class ChoosePersonPickingForm(ModelForm):

    picking_person_choices= None
    picking_person = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Pick Person', queryset=picking_person_choices, required=True)  
    #could be a ModelChoiceField if picking_person not actually ManyToMany

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['picking_person']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChoosePersonPickingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.picking_people_choices= Profile.objects.filter(members = self.instance)
        self.fields['picking_person'].queryset = self.picking_people_choices
```

Comment: There will be more than one Group, where same people can be added. Like choosing facebook group admin. Little correct - in last line should be self.picking_people_choices not self.pick_people_choices. Anyway - thanks very much, your method is working!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, and I have cleaned my typo. One note: If there's only one person picked per group (even if there are many groups and people can be picked for more than one ) then you can use the foreign key rather than many-to-many. This is more efficient as a manytomany creates an extra database table to handle the connection. In the djano docs, the foreign key example is: an article has one reporter, even though a reporter can have many articles. This is the same as a group having one person picked, but a person can be picked for many groups.

Comment: that's good point but I trying to change this model for foreign key, but i now have django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“None” is not a valid UUID.'] :/

Comment: You will need to run makemigrations and migrate after changing the model, and use ModelChoiceField in your form as I noted in the comment. If you're still getting the error, post the full trace and I can have a look at it.

Comment: I have this error when i trying to migrate. I ill try do something with it at weekend. Many thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437126/django-core-exceptions-validationerror-none-is-not-a-valid-uuid there is question with my problem