# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“None” is not a valid UUID.']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i'm trying to develop my app to heroku and i have this error:
I'm trying to delete database, or connect with AWS RDS, but still this error stops me. I was trying some --fake migrations, or delete migrations files but there shows other errors. Now i'm go back to first version and hope to find the solution.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        upload_to="profile_images/",
    )
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    draft_teams = models.ManyToManyField("Team", blank=True, related_name="draft_teams")
    id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["created"]
```

And error:

```
 Operations to perform:
      Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, fifa_draft, sessions, users
    Running migrations:
      Applying fifa_draft.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2614, in to_python
        return uuid.UUID(**{input_form: value})
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/uuid.py", line 168, in __init__
        hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
    AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'replace'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 290, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 131, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 163, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 248, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 131, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 599, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 345, in column_sql
    " ".join(
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 296, in _iter_column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 410, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1126, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 910, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2604, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/x/Desktop/projekty/draft_fifa/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2616, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“None” is not a valid UUID.']
```

0001_initial.py

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="Group",
            fields=[
                ("name", models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)),
                ("description", models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
                (
                    "featured_image",
                    models.ImageField(
                        blank=True, default="default.jpg", null=True, upload_to=""
                    ),
                ),
                ("password", models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ("created", models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                (
                    "number_of_players",
                    models.PositiveIntegerField(
                        default=18,
                        validators=[
                            django.core.validators.MinValueValidator(14),
                            django.core.validators.MaxValueValidator(20),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "draft_order_choice",
                    models.CharField(
                        choices=[("Serpentine", "Serpentine"), ("Fixed", "Fixed")],
                        default="Serpentine",
                        max_length=10,
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "id",
                    models.UUIDField(
                        default=uuid.uuid4,
                        editable=False,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        unique=True,
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={
                "ordering": ["created"],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="Profile",
            fields=[
                ("name", models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, null=True)),
                (
                    "username",
                    models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, null=True, unique=True),
                ),
                ("location", models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, null=True)),
                ("email", models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=50, null=True)),
                (
                    "short_intro",
                    models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250, null=True),
                ),
                (
                    "profile_image",
                    models.ImageField(
                        blank=True,
                        default="profile_images/user-default.png",
                        null=True,
                        upload_to="profile_images/",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "social_github",
                    models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True),
                ),
                (
                    "social_twitter",
                    models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True),
                ),
                (
                    "social_linkedin",
                    models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True),
                ),
                (
                    "social_youtube",
                    models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True),
                ),
                ("created", models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                (
                    "id",
                    models.UUIDField(
                        default=uuid.uuid4,
                        editable=False,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        unique=True,
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "user",
                    models.OneToOneField(
                        blank=True,
                        null=True,
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={
                "ordering": ["created"],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="Team",
            fields=[
                ("name", models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)),
                (
                    "featured_image",
                    models.ImageField(
                        blank=True, default="default.jpg", null=True, upload_to=""
                    ),
                ),
                ("created", models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ("group_password", models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ("max_players", models.PositiveIntegerField(default=14)),
                (
                    "id",
                    models.UUIDField(
                        default=uuid.uuid4,
                        editable=False,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        unique=True,
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "belongs_group",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        db_constraint=False,
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        to="fifa_draft.group",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "owner",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        default=fifa_draft.models.Profile,
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        to="fifa_draft.profile",
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={
                "ordering": ["created"],
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="group",
            name="members",
            field=models.ManyToManyField(
                blank=True,
                default=fifa_draft.models.Profile,
                related_name="members",
                to="fifa_draft.profile",
            ),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="group",
            name="owner",
            field=models.ForeignKey(
                db_constraint=False,
                default=fifa_draft.models.Profile,
                on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                to="fifa_draft.profile",
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

With older database app working good. Anyone can help?

Comment: Please show the relevant migration file

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. Desperate I deleted all migrations, did
`python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` and... it worked.